# Color of TextView in listview item changes automatically android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-filterable

So I am trying to use ListView to set the color of the text in my TextView to green when its clicked.
I also use Filterable with EditText's `addTextChangedListener` to search for items in my ArrayList.

The problem is when I click on a item the textview changes to green (as intended) but when i try to  search something else I see the color of the TextView inside the first item in my ListView goes green and the one i clicked changes back to white automatically.

EditText onTextChnagedListener:

```java
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()))
                {
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                }
                else
                {
                    listView.setFilterText(s.toString());
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

The onItemClickListener of ListView:

```java
View selectedView = null;
int selectedPositon = -1;
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                if(selectedPosition != -1)
                {
                    if(selectedView != null)
                    {
                        TextView textView = selectedView.findViewById(R.id.search_frag_listview_item_songname);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        selectedPosition = (int) id;
                        TextView selectedView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_frag_listview_item_songname);
                        selectedView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                        selectedView.setSelected(false);
                    }
                    selectedPosition = (int) id;
                    selectedView = view;
                }
                else
                {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_frag_listview_item_songname);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                    selectedView = view;
                    selectedPosition = (int) id;
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Example image of when I click item in ListView:
[image: img]

After I search something else without clicking on any item:
[image: img2]

How do I prevent the color of the TextView I selected from automatically changing in my ListView?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can store a boolean value in your model class, and  on click change the value false to true and notify the adapter, next time when you search some text then get the list of models from adapter and find if any true value set it to false and notify again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
View selectedView = null;
int selectedPositon = -1;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                if(selectedPosition != -1 && selectedView != null)
                    {
                        TextView textView = selectedView.findViewById(R.id.search_frag_listview_item_songname);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        selectedPosition = (int) id;
                        TextView selectedView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_frag_listview_item_songname);
                        selectedView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                        selectedView.setSelected(false);
                    }
                    selectedPosition = (int) id;
                    selectedView = view;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Comment: its still the same.